# CakePHP 2.x Cannot prevent deleted and banned user from logging in

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have a bit of code that prevents deleted and banned users from logging in. To clear minds a status of -2 means that the user is deleted, and -1 means that the user is banned. Below is the code which works fine on local, but on the live it sucks. users who have status of -1 or -2 are still able to login. I cannot find where the problem is.

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    //first check if the user's status is -1 or -2. 
    $status = $this->Auth->user('status');

    if ($status == '-1') {
        $this->Auth->logout();
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('This account has been banned. Please contact with us.'));
        $this->redirect('/');
    } elseif ($status == '-2') {
        $this->Auth->logout();
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('This account has been deleted, and is not usable anymore.'));
        $this->redirect('/');
    }

    //something else
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By calling `$this->Auth->login()` in the check you are logging the user in.

You could avoid this, and check the user information prior to login, or you could add the status flags to the scope for users.

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    AuthComponent::ALL => array(
        'userModel' => 'User',
        'scope' => array('User.status' => '> 0)
    ),
    'Form',
    'Basic'
);
```

This add the `status` field check to the login process.

If you want to customise messages as in your example, you can check the values on the user information before processing login:

```
$user = $this->User->findByUsername($this->data['User']['username']);
if (!empty($user)) {
    if ($user['User']['status'] == -1) {
        // Set message for banned account
    }
    if ($user['User']['status'] == -2) {
        // Set message for deleted account
    }
    $this->redirect( ... ); // Redirect away
}

if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    // Normal login process
}
```

Comment: I was not aware of the scope key, which is new in version 2.2. Thanks for the info! But this is not suitable for me right now. The second solution worked well in local, but not on live. I've done many debugs but still couldn't address the problem.

Comment: Hello again. Now it works on live site, too. I didn't do any commitment except deleting a cache file, which have the path app/tmp/cache/persisten/myapp_cake_core_file_map. That's weird!

Comment: The scope key is not new to CakePHP 2.

Answer (score 2):

The scope answer is the best, but there is a small error in the condition, instead of

```
'scope' => array('User.status' => '> 0)
```

the line should read

```
'scope' => array('User.status >' => 0)
```

which is the typical cakephp way to add comparison operators in condition arrays

(I would have just commented this, but it is easier to create an answer when new to this site.)